# Evaluate buffer in ghci or hugs via Emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, sml

Using sml-mode in Emacs I have been able to send my buffer contents directly to an inferior SML process using `C-c C-b`. Now I want to do the same thing only with Haskell. Haskell-mode does not seem to support this, so I'm wondering: What is the right way to go about this with Emacs and Haskell?

While learning SML I've been using `C-c C-b` almost non-stop to easily evaluate my program as I go, instantly seeing the results of assigning values etc. But if I use `C-c C-l` in haskell-mode on a saved file containing two lines, `let foo = "foo"` and `let bar = "bar"` - I get `"parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)"`

Comment: did your file with two lines have a `module <ModuleName> where` at the beginning?

Comment: It is now possible to run scripts (`:script <filename>`) of ghci statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are making a common rookie mistake, confusing what you can write inside the repl of ghci and what you write in a haskell source file.

All sml interpreters are made in such a way that you can write any top level declaration into the repl, or put in other words: anything you can write in an sml file, you can write into the sml interpreter. Thus you are allowed to write `val foo = "bar"` into a file and use `C-c C-b`  to load the file and you are allowed to just put in `val foo = "bar"` into the interpreter.

On the other hand, because of how haskell work, you can write `let foo = 42` into ghci, however it is not a valid top level declaration and thus this can't be in a haskell source file (by it self). On the other hand you can have `id n = n` in a haskell source file and use `C-c C-l` to load the file, however you can't write this directly into ghci (you will get an error: :1:6: parse error on input '='). The reason for this is that the repl in ghci runs in the IO monad, and thus what ever you write into ghci must be done using the do notation. I can only recommend that you read [Interactive evaluation at the prompt](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) from the Using GHCi user guide.

`C-c C-b` in sml-mode is the exact same thing as `C-c C-l` in haskell-mode, well atleast conceptually. I don't know that much about the internals of haskell-mode, but in sml-mode `C-c C-b` executes some sml code in the interpreter, normally the `use(...)` function. In haskell-mode it seems to just excute the `:load "..."` ghci command

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that with ghci (or hugs) for the simple reason that you can't write top-level definitions in ghci (or hugs). So even if you manually pasted your file's contents into ghci, all you'd get would be a syntax error.

So loading a file using C-c C-l is the best you can do.

Comment: Jfyi, GHC 7.4 will allow for top-level data/type/newtype definitions in GHCi